# How to access dynamic controls having same properties in the Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, css-selectors

I am having a aspx page,in which there is a Select box control

```
<select name="selViewPerPage" id="selViewPerPage" style="width:30px">
```

In order to bring a particular style in all browsers, i am replacing this html control with dynamic select box using "selectBox.js" . Now the problem is , i am having two dropdowns in the page ,during runtime they are generated with same class  name without any ids.So while trying to position the controls using css,the both drop downs takes the same position. [image: Please see the html code in firebug]

So i am not sure ,how to handle this situation .Please let me know,if you  need more information.

Thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a pseudo-selector to get just a specific item, such as the first, last, or nth item.  See **:eq()** or **:first()** or **:last()** for example: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.  Using one of those sorts of selectors, you can get just the element you want to modify and apply styles to it individually.  Ex.

```
$('ul').first()
```

or

```
$('ul:last')
```

or

```
$('ul').eq(1)
```

Or some other variant of these.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple instances of items with the same class, use the `.eq()` selector.

```
$('.someSelect').eq(0) <-- first instance
$('.someSelect').eq(1) <-- second instance
```